# Using requests to send POST request to Mixcloud

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

I am using the service called [Mixcloud](http://www.mixcloud.com/) to try and upload some hour long podcast like mp3 files. I have been following Mixclouds documentation on how I should be uploading a song via a post request using their [api](http://www.mixcloud.com/developers/documentation/), however I am getting some error.

They say to submit a `multipart/form-data` POST request with all the data required in one single post request. Based on what they said here is the Python code I came up with using [requests](http://python-requests.org) to POST with:

```
accessToken = '**Censored**'
postUrl = 'https://api.mixcloud.com/upload/?access_token=' + accessToken
#postUrl = 'http://requestb.in/wqqj8lwq'  ---> For testing what POST request sends.

files = {'mp3': open('/home/jhvisser/Music/driveAt5_'+now.strftime("%y%m%d")+'.mp3', 'rb'),
    'name': 'z103.5 Drive at 5 Streetmix - '+now.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
    'tags-0-tag': 'remix',
    'tags-1-tag': 'radio',
    'tags-2-tag': 'hits',
    'description': 'Daily weekday uploads of the latest drive at 5 music hits'
}

r = requests.post(postUrl,files=files)
```

I get the following JSON back in response to the post:

```
{
    "details": {
        "name": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    },
    "error": {
        "message": "Some posted data was invalid",
        "type": "PostValidationError"
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it is saying that I am missing the name field. I have a name field. It is possible that the other fields may gives errors too except I'm not sure if the Mixcloud application just stops validation upon an error or not.

I also made a POST request to [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/wqqj8lwq?inspect) so that you can take a look at what exactly is being posted from this request. I will include a link below to a pastebin of the requestbin page as I believe the links expire on RequestBin

[PasteBin Mirror](http://pastebin.com/nyTs9fqu)

For comparison sake here is what their example on the API page shows to do if using CURL:

```
curl -F mp3=@cloudcast.mp3 \
     -F "name=API Upload" \
     -F "tags-0-tag=Test" \
     -F "tags-1-tag=API" \
     -F "sections-0-chapter=Introduction" \
     -F "sections-0-start_time=0" \
     -F "sections-1-artist=Artist Name" \
     -F "sections-1-song=Song Title" \
     -F "sections-1-start_time=10" \
     -F "percentage_music=75" \
     -F "description=My test cloudcast" \
     https://api.mixcloud.com/upload/?access_token=INSERT_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://www.mixcloud.com/developers/documentation/#uploads) and the error you get, you should give a name

> name   REQUIRED. The name of the cloudcast - this will be used to generate the URL, duplicate names should be avoided but will not cause an upload to fail.

**Update**

as mentioned in the comment, sending the following values using the optional parameter data uploads the file

```
 data={
    'name': 'z103.5 Drive at 5 Streetmix - '+now.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
    'tags-0-tag': 'remix',
    'tags-1-tag': 'radio',
    'tags-2-tag': 'hits',
    'description': 'Daily weekday uploads of the latest drive at 5 music hits'
 }
 r = requests.post(postUrl,files=files,data=data)
```

Comment: i may be wrong but the name may have to be in the data parametet instaed of files. i guess the error you get from the api should mean that somehow it couldnt find the name you send

Comment: i think the files parameter should have only a file, and the `requests.post` function has optional parameter `data`.

Comment: no sorry i was wrong i uploaded one on the browser, let me update the answer

Comment: interesting, i'll try get an api tomorrow and mess around, i think for some reason the server couldnt find the name

Comment: Well I tried doing it the other way and having them separate and this time I get a success message and it uploaded, however I am having playback issues on the page. I guess your answer kind of solved it but you should edit this in. I don't know why the playback on the site isn't working, however that is not a problem for Stack. Edit: here is my new code: http://pastebin.com/ZtLyaFJx